# Obtain full size of colorbar in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, position, matlab-figure, colorbar

I am writing a plot automation routine for Matlab.
However, I am having issues to assess the (horizontal) size of colorbars.
I can use the following to get the size of the colorbar:

```
cb = findall(groot,'Type','colorbar'); % get colorbar
xwidth = cb.Position(3);
```

This will give me the horizontal size of the colorbar, but EXCLUDES labels and tick labels.

Do you have an idea how to obtain the full size of both the bar and the labels?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: @Suever: 2017a prerelease

Comment: In general, it's best not to ask questions in a public forum about pre-release software due to the confidential nature. That being said, this question pertains to all versions of MATLAB after R2014b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions of MATLAB prior to R2014b, a colorbar was simply an `axes` object in disguise so you could easily use the `OuterPosition` property of the colorbar to get the position of the colorbar (including labels and tick labels). However, in R2014b, the colorbar is it's own graphics object and the underlying axes is no longer accessible.

One possible workaround is to create an invisible `axes` object on top of the colorbar (that has the same tick marks and labels) and get the `OuterPosition` of *that*.

```
function pos = getColorbarPosition(cb)

    tmp = axes('Position', cb.Position, 'YAxisLocation', 'right', ...
            'YLim', cb.Limits, 'FontSize', cb.FontSize, 'Units', cb.Units, ...
            'FontWeight', cb.FontWeight, 'Visible', 'off', ...
            'FontName', cb.FontName, 'YTick', cb.Ticks, ...
            'YTickLabels', cb.TickLabels, 'XTick', []);

    if ~isempty(cb.Label)
        ylabel(tmp, cb.Label.String, 'FontSize', cb.Label.FontSize, ...
        'FontWeight', cb.Label.FontWeight, 'FontWeight', cb.Label.FontWeight)
    end

    pos = get(tmp, 'OuterPosition');

    delete(tmp);
end
```

Comment: I already expected a somewhat lengthy workaround, but that works for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: I found that you also needed to add `'TickDir',cb.TickDirection` to the axes initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In the matlab2017 the colorbar objects have two important size properties, 'Position' and 'Label.Extent'

```
cax = colorbar;
cax.Units = 'centimeters'; % I think this sets the units for the child
cax.Label.String = 'A title'; 
% The position of the bar itself as [ left bottom width height ]
cpos = cax1.Position; 
% The position of the label as [ left bottom width height ]
lpos = cax.Label.Extent;
% The width of the colorbar and label is:
totalwidth = cpos(3) + lpos(3)
```